# How to handle a Promise in a Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, protractor

I have a piece of code below:

```
browser.sleep(2000).then(function(){
  element.all(by.xpath('one xpath')).then(function(elements){
   for(let elm of elements){
     elm.getText().then(function(text){
      if(text == "ButtonA"){
        elm.click();
      }
    })
   }
 })
});

funcB();
```

The `funcB()` had executed before `elm.click()`
I know, that I have used Promise in a for-Loop. And it make mistake. And I have already tried some solutions that I've found in internet, but so far I haven't found how to make `elm.click()` work before `funcB` run. Please help!

Comment: `Promise.all(element.all...).then(() => funcB())` should work.

Comment: `elem.click()` might _itself_ do asynchronous work - are you expecting to wait for that asynchronous work to _also_ complete? Moreover, we dont know what `elem` actually is (an HTML Button maybe?) and whether it supports Promises or callbacks to notify when it's done

Comment: @Jamiec: elements = [Button, ButtonA, ButtonB, ButtonC, ButtonD]. I want to find out ButtonA first and then click ButtonA, finally run funcB()

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: I've tried it, but funcB() is in another File. My post here is ony a example. The first peace of code is in common.js and the function funcB() is in somehelper.js

Comment: so... put it after the loop. i don't understand the confusion.

Comment: I think everyone had this question when they started. At least I did too. I don't know why all these downvotes keep coming

Answer (score 0):

You will be surprised that protractor can be used by schoolchildren if you use `async/await` instead of `.then` like so

```
it('test case', async () => {
  await browser.sleep(2000)
  let elementArrayName = element.all(by.xpath('one xpath'));
  for (let i = 0; i<await elementArrayName.count(); i++) {
    let text = await elementArrayName.get(i).getText();
    if(text === "ButtonA"){
      await elementArrayName.get(i).click();
    }
  }

  // IMPORTANT!
  // I don't know what your funcB is, 
  // but I have a feeling it returns a promise and thus needs await too
  await funcB();
});
```

How do you like your code now?

So both `.then` and `await` instruct javascript to stop until the promise is resolved, but the second one doesnt require you to build these endless Khufu pyramids and keeps things simple, readable and debuggable

Comment: @MusterTester let me know if that works for you